# How to insert rows to table view when user scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with a real time data table view. New data will be inserted to the top of table view by seconds. I use the following code to insert rows.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

It works well when staying at the top of the table view. But when the user scrolls, new cells flash with weird animation. And content offset will be changed every second. This is very bad user experience. But I have no idea.

Comment: You need to show more relevant code.

Comment: and add if you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or how do you compute `rowHeight`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Fixed row height.

Comment: If everything else is correct then perhaps you should set `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` because then table view itself decides best suited animation.

Comment: why not just use reloadData?

Comment: @FahimParkar For performance optimization.